# PHP classes - having trouble declaring one

Tags: php, oop

I'm using Crackstation.net's PHP source code for hashing + salting passwords.

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode

I'm trying to put this code in a class, for ease of use.

I figured I could do it with the extra line "class PasswordHasher{" at the top of the code, and a nice closing bracket.

```
<?php    

class PasswordHasher{
// These constants may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);

//all functions from the URL source

}
?>
```

For some reason, Netbeans does not want me using the define keyword this way inside of a class. If I have all the define lines above the class decleration, I don't get any syntax errors from Netbeans. I'm pretty new to PHP, and I can't find the reason of this behaviour. What am I doing wrong, and how do I turn this source code into a class for OO programming?

Comment: You are looking for class `const`ants. [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

Comment: Actually, just looked at that `Crackstation` code. It uses constants defined outside of the class. So your only option is to leave them there.

Comment: please, read the fine manual

Comment: Use `password_hash()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `const` for classes:

```
const PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM = "sha256";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute code inside a `class`, OUTSIDE of the bounds of a method.

```
class foo {
    $bar = 1 + 1; // illegal - not in a method
    function baz() {
       $this->bar = 1 + 1; // legal, inside a method.
    }
}
```